# change html object inside cloned object

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

supose i have tr like this :

```
<tr id="file" >
            <td width="510"><div align="right"><span class="star"> *</span>
                <input type="text" name="title" style="width:500px;direction:ltr"  />
            </div></td>
            <td width="156" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="right">file </div></td>
          </tr>
```

and i have to link at bottom of page that let me do some action my js code is :

```
$(function(){

        $(".add").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var copy =$('#file').clone().removeAttr('id').insertBefore($('.submit')) ;


            console.log('add called') ;
        });

        $('.remove').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('remove called ');
        });     


    }) ;
```

if the user first input some text in first input i have the same text in copy , i want to clear input after i create copy . tanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`.val('')`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in the chain to clear the value, like this:

```
$('#file').clone().removeAttr('id').insertBefore('.submit')
                  .find('input').val('');
```

This searches inside the cloned element to clear the `<input>` it finds.  If you need to be more specific later, you can use `.find('input[name=title]')`.  If you need that `copy` reference, just add a [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) after the [`.val('')`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) call so you're referencing the `<tr>` and not the `<input>` with it.

Comment: @mehdi - You pass it an empty string like the example above, this set it to empty.  *Not* passing anything would get the value.